# C# Multi level HTML TagBuilder object - Design pattern Review needed

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I find the TagBuilder written in C# little poor without the ability to "host" inside it sub tags (as objects not as strings).

So I wrote a simple class that inherits TagBuilder and allow to save sub tags.
I can navigate inside it and add things to it while I move across the application.
And when I call the Top Tag Object .ToString, it will render the entire html

```
public class MultiLevelHtmlTag : TagBuilder
{
    public MultiLevelHtmlTag(string tagName) : base(tagName) { }

    public List<MultiLevelHtmlTag> InnerTags = new List<MultiLevelHtmlTag>();



    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (InnerTags.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (MultiLevelHtmlTag tag in InnerTags)
            {
                this.InnerHtml += tag.ToString();
            }
        }
        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

this is how I use it:

```
MultiLevelHtmlTag top = new MultiLevelHtmlTag("div");
top.InnerTags.Add(new MultiLevelHtmlTag("span"));
log.Debug(top.ToString());
```

output:

```
<div><span></span></div>
```

What do you think about it?
is that a goot pattern?

Comment: I would create a separate class for all valid HTML tags, and apply the Composite pattern.

Comment: You have some fundamental issues in your code. Your `ToString()` method has some major problems. See what happens if you call it multiple times. It should only return a string representation of the object. It shouldn't be modifying it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would make sure the list is not exposed publicly - the caller can then do whatever they want with that list, even assign `null` to it.  So I've refactored it a little bit and implemented `Add()` (you may also want to implement `Remove()`, etc.):

```
/// <summary>
/// Simple class that inherits TagBuilder and allow to save sub tags.
/// </summary>
public class MultiLevelHtmlTag : TagBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List of inner tags.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IList<MultiLevelHtmlTag> innerTags = new List<MultiLevelHtmlTag>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MultiLevelHtmlTag"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tagName">The name of the tag.</param>
    public MultiLevelHtmlTag(string tagName) : base(tagName)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the inner tag list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The inner tag list.</value>
    public IEnumerable<MultiLevelHtmlTag> InnerTags
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<MultiLevelHtmlTag>(this.innerTags);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified tag to the inner tag list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tag">The tag to add.</param>
    public void Add(MultiLevelHtmlTag tag)
    {
        if (tag == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("tag");
        }

        this.innerTags.Add(tag);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var tag in this.innerTags)
        {
            sb.Append(tag.ToString());
        }

        this.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great response; in my project I've just changed the inner tags to be `TagBuilder` (so that I can add "regular" `TagBuilder` objects to it); there's no actual need to have them as `MultiLevelHtmlTag`s.

Comment: @ANeves - you need to use concat your results to the existing inner text or else you will end up with all empty tags.